# Trigger.io + set page footer

Tags: trigger.io

I am facing a problem with setting the footer for one of my pages with trigger.io.
The problem is that i do not want to set up the footer using any hard-coded value in css. The current css(below)  & HTML code works fine but here the position is hard-coded.

```
.copyright-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 55px;
}
```

HTML code:

```
   <div id="copyright-text" class="copyright-text">
    copyrght @ appleISNotmine.inc
   </div>
```

Is there any way that i can set the footer which **always sticks to the bottom of the page?**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
top: 300px;
```

Use:

```
bottom: 0px;
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/FBD92/